# How to Make a Field Required in Edit Form using PreSaveAction

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How to make a field required on the edit form. I have this field called "Approver Email" and "approver name". It does not appear on the Default Form since I am using a templet to hide it. I can't set it as required at the site column level because the system will not save the New form without that field completed. Is there any way to add code to a script editor to check If those column are empty before saving/submitting it?

Also, I am using another pre-save action to do different task on that page, does it matter if I use 2 pre-save action to do two different task?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter that it's already in the PreSaveAction() as long as it doesn't interfere with your other actions. But what you can do, may not be the best, but in the PreSaveAction get the use the id of the text area and see if the value is what you desire or not. Return

```
function PreSaveAction() {   
    var _value = document.getElementById("insertIdHere").value

    if(_value) return true

    alert("Approver cannot be left blank");
    return false;   
}
```

This will get the value and see if it has anything, if so it returns true and saves the entry. Otherwise it will alert and return false (which prevents the list entry from saving and allowing the filling in of the field).